# Mouse hesitates as it approaches bottom of monitor screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, external-monitor

I have recently started using a 27" dell monitor with my xps 13 (7390) running 22.04.1. My display settings are as follows: using single display mode, landscape orientation, resolution 3840x2160 (autodetected from monitor), 60hz (auto), scale 175% using fractional scaling. When my mouse reaches maybe 1.5" from the bottom of the screen, it hesitates before moving further to reach the bottom, like it's caught. I'm guessing this is part of the downside of using fractional scaling? (Edit: the issue persists at 150% but not 200%, hence my guess.) If that's the price, I'm willing to pay it, 200% is too big. But if there's a way to fix it, that would be great. Thanks!

Edit: As per comment below,the changing the refresh rate,  resulted in the screen going black and resetting to 60hz. As for drivers, my graphics needed none and installing a firmware update for the monitor does not seem possible through linux, windows only release from dell.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my question based on this.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the exact same problem on a Thinkpad T14 Gen 3.

I thought this was caused by a upgrade of ubuntu 22.04 because:

- No problem with the 22.04.2 USB startup disk
- No problem with the 22.10 USB startup disk

So I upgraded to ubuntu 22.10 but... I still can't reach the bottom of the screen with the mouse (exactly as you phrase it: the mouse "hesitates", or I could say stutters and is basically unusable).

Lowering the resolution "fixes" the problem but it's very disappointing to downgrade a 4K screen like this.

If I find something I'll keep you posted.

Comment: This could be a wayland problem. Using Xorg apprently solves this (also this makes the mouse much slower).

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue here. Mouse get's "sticky" around the bottom of the screen, leaving line type artefacts sometimes.